# Elements with border radius and overflow hidden don't clip the content properly: 1px issue

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm playing with buttons and came across this issue. When the button has rounded corners and there is an before pseudo element inside of it to simulate background (used for transition), I am getting a 1px issue. The before pseudo element isn't clipped properly and you can barely see some sort of space between the border of the button and the fill color. Check out the examples:

You will see that on rounded buttons, there is a tiny line/space between the border and the fill of the element.

Any clues on how to eliminate it while keeping the structure the same?

EDIT 1. I know I could use background instead, but I can't do it in this case. Background has to be done via pseudo element.

EDIT 2. Issue can be seen on Win 10, Chrome and Firefox. Firefox makes it more visible. Newest versions: Chrome 60.0.3112.78, Firefox 54.0.1

EDIT 3. Edited the code to show why I can't use background property.

```css
a {
  color: black
}

.anibtn {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  margin: 0 3px 6px 3px;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 10px black;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: $btncolor;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.anibtn-round {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  margin: 0 3px 6px 3px;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 10px black;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: $btncolor;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 50px;
}


.tr-fill-on {
  position: relative;
  transition-duration: .3s;
}

.tr-fill-on:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background: black;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
  
.tr-fill-on:hover {
  color: white;
}

.tr-fill-on:hover:before {
  width:100%;
}




.tr-fill2-on{
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  transition-duration: .3s;
}
.tr-fill2-on:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background: black;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.tr-fill2-on:hover {
  color: black;
}

.tr-fill2-on:hover:before {
  width:0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="anibtn tr-fill-on">Ani Buttons</a>
<a href="#" class="anibtn tr-fill2-on">Ani Buttons</a>
<a href="#" class="anibtn-round tr-fill-on">Ani Buttons</a>
<a href="#" class="anibtn-round tr-fill2-on">Ani Buttons</a>
```

Comment: Works fine on Mac chrome... which browser has issue?

Comment: Chrome and Firefox on Win 10. Firefox makes it more visible. Newest versions.

Comment: I can see the issue on Firefox...

Comment: This is because the anti-aliasing applied for the rounded corners combined with the :before pseudo-element placed behind the actual element with the rounded corners. Not sure though what the solution be might be, I thought I put this here... maybe it will help you/someone to figure it out.

Comment: @ZoliSzabó I just increased the border thickness in the script above for better visibility. Thanks, I will try to put the before element above the actual button and text above both to see if that works. EDIT - doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pseudo elements for background (for dynamic effect) and using the actual background (for smoothness of inner border edge) aren't mutually exclusive. If the container is a root of the stacking context, it's background will be always painted below any descendants, even those with negative z-index. Setting black background to the button (1), making it the root of the stacking context (2) and making pseudo-elements two-color with each half a bit bigger than the inner area of the button and animating its position instead of width seems to solve the white pixels problem.

I used single-color gradient instead of a solid color for the button background to prevent black-on-black button text in browsers that don't support gradients (like Opera Mini). The animation can be even smoother if change `transform:translateX` or even `transform:translate3d` instead of `left`.

```css
a {
  color: black
}

.anibtn {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  margin: 0 3px 6px 3px;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 10px black;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: $btncolor;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: linear-gradient(black,black); /* 1 */
}

.anibtn-round {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  margin: 0 3px 6px 3px;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 10px black;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: $btncolor;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(black,black); /* 1 */
}


.tr-fill-on {
  position: relative;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  z-index: 1; /* 2 */
}

.tr-fill-on:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, white, white 50%, black 50%);
  transition: all .3s;
  z-index: -1;
  left: -1%;
  top: -1%;
  width: 204%;
  height: 102%;
}
  
.tr-fill-on:hover {
  color: white;
}

.tr-fill-on:hover:before {
  left: -103%;
}




.tr-fill2-on{
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  z-index: 1; /* 2 */
}
.tr-fill2-on:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';      
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, white, white 50%, black 50%);
  transition: all .3s;
  z-index: -1;
  left: -103%;
  top: -1%;
  width: 204%;
  height: 102%;
}
.tr-fill2-on:hover {
  color: black;
}

.tr-fill2-on:hover:before {
  left: -1%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="anibtn tr-fill-on">Ani Buttons</a>
<a href="#" class="anibtn tr-fill2-on">Ani Buttons</a>
<a href="#" class="anibtn-round tr-fill-on">Ani Buttons</a>
<a href="#" class="anibtn-round tr-fill2-on">Ani Buttons</a>
```

Comment: I like your solution and I've been experimenting with this same idea but unfortunately, this won't work as the button has to be transparent in its resting state, in case if there is a background image on the container. 
What I will probably end up doing is giving the button `transition-duration: 0;` and switching the background from black to transparent, so the pixels will only be visible during the pseudo element transformation.

Comment: I will accept your answer as I used a variation of this idea to fix this issue in a bit hacky way :)

Answer (score 3):

EDIT :

I could not find the problem, but I found another way to do it ;)

instead of setting a `border`, make it a `border-shadow`

```
.anibtn-round {
  /* border: solid 2px black; */
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px black;
}
```

Now that line will go away ;)

Comment: Ehh... because there will be tens of other transitions, like background sliding up or down, which can't be achieved without a pseudo element.

Comment: The before element is 100% width and 100% height.

Comment: Why downvoting my comment and then updating your question aa?

Comment: Edit was done before your comment, but fair enough :)

Comment: :D. Perhaps I was writing when you edited this :D. 
Well might this be a problem with the browser rendering (webkit)

Comment: Now It creates a space between the boxshadow and the border. So it's still there but bit closer to the edge

Comment: border? as I said delete `border:solid 2px black`

Answer (score 0):

If not required you can remove `overflow: hidden;` and `white-space: nowrap;` and hopefully it will help you.

```css
a {
  color: black
}

.anibtn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  margin: 0 3px 6px 3px;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 10px black;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: $btncolor;
}

.anibtn-round {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  margin: 0 3px 6px 3px;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 10px black;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: $btncolor;
  border-radius: 50px;
}


.tr-fill-on {
  position: relative;
  transition-duration: .3s;
}

.tr-fill-on:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background: black;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
  
.tr-fill-on:hover {
  color: white;
}

.tr-fill-on:hover:before {
  width:100%;
}




.tr-fill2-on{
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  transition-duration: .3s;
}
.tr-fill2-on:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background: black;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.tr-fill2-on:hover {
  color: black;
}

.tr-fill2-on:hover:before {
  width:0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="anibtn tr-fill-on">Ani Buttons</a>
<a href="#" class="anibtn tr-fill2-on">Ani Buttons</a>
<a href="#" class="anibtn-round tr-fill-on">Ani Buttons</a>
<a href="#" class="anibtn-round tr-fill2-on">Ani Buttons</a>
```